# Transformation of matrix by criteria

Tags: r, matrix

Professionals of R, I have a question: 
I have the matrix as below, and I want create the criteria: to construct the matrix using only the next strings: `1st string + i`, where `i=3` so I want to get the new matrix with the first, 5th, 9th strings of the initial matrix, and so the dimension of new matrix has to be `3x3`. Maybe is there the special function in R for this procedure or needed to realize this task through the FUN in R?

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2   15
 [2,]    2    3   16
 [3,]    3    4    1
 [4,]    4    5    2
 [5,]    5    6    3
 [6,]    6    7    4
 [7,]    7    8    5
 [8,]    8    9    6
 [9,]    9   10    7
```

Below the desired matrix:

```
    1    2   15
    5    6    3
    9   10    7
```

Comment: Could you show your desired output?

Comment: How about `apply(m1, 2, '[', c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))`

Comment: I think you want this: `your_matrix[seq(1, ncol(your_matrix), by = 4), ]`... it seems like 1 +4 = 5 and 5 + 4 = 9, so I think you mean `i = 4` not `i = 3`, but maybe I'm wrong about everything?

Comment: If I use this formula: your_matrix[seq(1, ncol(your_matrix), by = 4), ], R prints only the first string. Are you do something wrong?

Comment: @Mukhtar Try to replace `ncol` with `nrow` with Gregor's code.